# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException

Tags: java, hibernate, servlets

I am new to Hibernate,servlets. I am trying to store data in mysql database  using hibernate from html registration form.. But I am keep getting this error as root cause.
here is the two root causes pop up.

```
HTTP status 500 Internal server error.

Exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
Root Cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/PersistenceException
    java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1007)
    java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2339)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:829)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1278)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1137)
    kish.hibernate.servletController.registerData.doGet(registerData.java:30)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
Root Cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1309)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1137)
    java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1007)
    java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2339)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:829)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1278)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1137)
    kish.hibernate.servletController.registerData.doGet(registerData.java:30)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

here is my hibernate.cfg.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configurationn>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">Kish</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property> <!-- create table every time -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <mapping class="kish.hibernate.Pojo.Student"></mapping>

    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configurationn>
```

here is my html file

```
<html> 
<head>
<title> RegistrationForm</title>
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "style1.css">
<body>


  <div class= "registrationBox">
        <img src= "avatar1.png" class= "avatar">
     <h1> enter your details below form</h1>   

<form action = "registerData" method ="get"> 
    <p>Firstname</p>
    <input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="Enter your firstname">
   <p>Lastname</p>
   <input type = "text" name= "last_name" placeholder="Your lastname ">
   <p>Branch</p>
   <input type = "text" name="branch" placeholder="your branch">
   <p>Id</p>
   <input type = "text" name = "Id" placeholder="your id">
   <p>password</p>
   <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="create your password">
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value = "confirm">
 </form>
</div>

</body>
</head>
</html>
```

servlet file registerData.java

```
[package kish.hibernate.servletController;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import kish.hibernate.DAO.MainController;

@WebServlet("/registerData")
public class registerData extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public registerData() {
        super();
    }


    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String first_name = request.getParameter("first_name");
        String last_name = request.getParameter("last_name");
        String branch = request.getParameter("branch");
        int Id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("Id"));
        String password = request.getParameter("password");


        MainController mc = new MainController();
        mc.addUserDeatails(first_name, last_name, branch, Id, password);
        response.sendRedirect("success");

    }

}
```

I will post any further data if needed.

Any suggestions appreciated.
  Thanks.

Edit:

"javax.persistence.jar"

It clearly contains "javax.persistence.PersistenceException.class"

added this jar and still showing the same error.

[updated jar file in classpath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPYTf.png)

Comment: This message suggests that you're missing a JAR dependency: https://www.findjar.com/class/javax/persistence/PersistenceException.html

Comment: It is showing me stack of jars I have no idea which one should i exactly use.

Comment: The class you're missing is in all of those JARs.  Pick the best one for your situation, add it to your CLASSPATH, and see what the next error is.

Comment: If Maven did indeed pull that dependency down, I'd check your package creation to see if it was added correctly.

Comment: I added the jar file manually to class path..I am not using Maven. I showed that code as instance.

Comment: persistence-api is a good, generic choice.  I'd recommend Maven when you're ready.  If you still got that error, you didn't add the JAR to classpath correctly.  Why are you using something as complex as Hibernate for such a simple use case?  This looks like it could be a single table that you access using JDBC.  Is your wish to learn Hibernate?

Comment: jar files image updated; I can use JDBC but I am learning hibernate. It may be simple case for now. I want to know how to achieve it using hibernate.

Comment: It could be your web server.  If you are using WebLogic you need a weblogic.xml file in addition to web.xml.  In weblogic.xml, you can use
container-descriptor and prefer-application-packages tags to override using server resources (which may not be there).

Comment: @BigFish No. I am using tomcat server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your jar under **WEB-INF/lib folder**. Build your project.It will work.

Comment: Thanks alot..finally a breakthrough after being hunted for 9 hours. You gave me a clue. I kept checking errors, adding required jars to WEB-INF/lib folder, I have to add 18 jar files..Unakku Nandri.

Comment: Nanri kishore ;-)

Answer (score 0):

ClassNotFoundException comes when JVM tries to the load a class at runtime dynamically

NoClassDefFoundError the problematic class was present during Compile time and that's why the program successfully compiled but not available during runtime for any reason

Please check your class path. Since its maven please check the lib folder path in your setting.xml and check if the jar is available in m2.repository.

Comment: It's not maven project..btw

Answer (score 0):

The solution is, add below shown jar files

to WEB-INF/lib folder.

[jar files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6wMo.png)